# Javascript not working on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

In my web page I've the following javascript function that is called onLoad in the body:

```
function changeDivWidth()
{   
    d = document.getElementById('background');   
    document.getElementById("backgroundImg").style.height = window.innerHeight+"px";
    imgWidth = document.getElementById("backgroundImg").width;
    marginLeft = ($(window).width() - imgWidth)/2;   
    d.style.width = imgWidth+"px";
    d.style.left = marginLeft+"px";
    document.getElementById("backgroundImg").style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById("menu").style.visibility="visible";
}
```

This script basically takes the height of the browser page and set it as height of an Element.
This is working pretty fine in all browser except in IE7 and IE8, where the script is not loaded.
Can you suggest me a solution?

Thanks

Comment: The script isn't loaded? Or the height/width it grabs are wrong? Any error messages? Can we see a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of it breaking?

Comment: basic debugging of alerting variables would probably lead you to the answer why. Why you are mixing jQuery and regular DOM is a little strange and it lead to your issue.

Comment: Rewrite it using jquery or other js-dom library, to avoid browser incompatibility.

Comment: You should also defined your variables using var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.innerHeight` doesn't work in IE8 and below. Try out `document.body.clientHeight`

Edit: Wait a minute... are you using jQuery on line 6?:

```
marginLeft = ($(window).width() - imgWidth)/2;
```

If you are, then use `$(window).height()` to get the height instead.

Comment: The answer before the edit was the answer to my problem!
Thank you very much for the help!